# query ldap: Get MACHINE NAME from USERNAME

Tags: vbscript, ldap, ado

I want to be able to run a vbscript that queries the LDAP in order to get the current logged-on machine name (if any), from a given username.

I already have code that queries things related only to user (like email and name, GIVEN username) or that gets the machine name from the active person's environment.

But I want to be able to pass any username and see if they are logged on, return their machine name.

Is it possible?  I have been trying to cobble together various things with no success.

Comment: I don't think there is a quick way. I would get a list of all the computer names on the AD, check if they are online and if so, make a WMIService query `SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem` on that computer and look for `UserName`. This will give you the active logged on user on that computer.

Comment: most of the time in companies a script is executed when logging on, you can store all kind of stuff in logs, databases etc and query this info later on

Comment: peter - totally agree, this is what I would love to control, and there is a slight possibility that I can gain agreement among the users involved to add such a logon script to their daily lives, but I'm outside IT so I can't force the issue, this is more of a creative idea coming from non-IT developer role.Patrick - thanks, I will try that - sounds good, although I'm not sure how to do the second part....